# Do integers wrap around in ARMv6 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

If I start with integer `1` and repeatedly `LSL` the value in the register, once the integer overflows, what is the intended behaviour?

```
mov r0,#1 /* 00000000000000000000000000000001 */
lsl r0,#1 /* 00000000000000000000000000000010 */
/* repeat 31 times */
lsl r0,#1 /* 10000000000000000000000000000000 */
```

On the next LSL, should the program:

1. Crash
2. Set r0 back to 1
3. Something else? r0 = 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From section A2.2.1 of the v6-M reference manual, "Integer arithmetic", subsection "Shift and rotate operations":

> (LSL) moves each bit of a bitstring left by a specified number of bits. Zeros are shifted in at
>   the right end of the bitstring. Bits that are shifted off the left end of the bitstring are
>   discarded, except that the last such bit can be produced as a carry output.

Therefore it becomes 0 and the carry flag is set.

Comment: Useful, thank you. So I can look at the carry to conditionally wrap it back around to 1 myself? Is there an instruction I'm not aware of that allows me to intentionally keep moving the on-bit left and then back to 1 again when it would wrap around, or will this always involve multiple instructions? (I'm shifting in a loop that goes forever and trying to find the solution with the least instructions).

Comment: It will involve multiple instructions. Try `ADC` (or the ARM equivalent) next.

Comment: @dwelch: Those rotate through the carry flag.

Comment: understood.  I thought the rotate right was the one with lots of special cases but looked it up and it isnt.  So perhaps lsl plus adc is the best way to get a rotate left.